# Where does --file look for Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I've created a simple file structure:

```
.
└── docker-test
    ├── abc.txt
    └── Dockerfile
```

The following executions work successfully:

1. `docker build ./docker-test`
2. `docker build --file ./docker-test/Dockerfile ./docker-test`
3. `docker build --file Dockerfile ./docker-test`

I am confused why both commands 2 and 3 work. The `--file` arguments are different, and I am not sure how to interpret this. When specifying relative path in `--file`, what should it be relative to? The current directory? Or the build context (`./docker-test/`)? It seems that both options are valid, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a `./Dockerfile` file?

Comment: I'm sure. I showed the contents of my current directory. It's a fresh directory that contains only `docker-test` directory.

Comment: With Docker version 24.0.7, command **3** doesn't work (`ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1055130434/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`).

Comment: Interesting, I'm using podman, which is supposed to have CLI compatible with docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems like it is documented:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files

> By default the docker build command will look for a Dockerfile at the root of the build context. The -f, --file, option lets you specify the path to an alternative file to use instead. This is useful in cases where the same set of files are used for multiple builds. **The path must be to a file within the build context. If a relative path is specified then it is interpreted as relative to the root of the context.**

But, clearly, it contradicts what you are experiencing so maybe you found a bug.